# QDialog: how to set fixed size on mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qwidget, qdialog

I'm using qt 4.8.5. On Windows I can set fixed size flag to a dialog with

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
```

Is there similar way to set fixed size dialog on Mac? I don't want to use `setFixedSize()` method to hard-code the dialog size.

Comment: why do you avoid `setFixedSize`? The reason would help formulate a good answer.

Comment: There is no similar to Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint specific flag on Mac

Comment: @UmNyobe, Because I want to update the text on the dialog while the dialog is visible to user, that may resize the dialog, So I don't want to hard-code to a fixed size. And I want to disable the resize by user from UI.